# In Rails 7 can one use import maps along with a js bundling solution or are they exclusive?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, ruby-on-rails-7, import-maps

I'm starting to get my head around the new import maps functionality in rails 7. It seems there are a lot of advantages of using this functionality.

It seems however if I need a transpile step (eg JSX) that I need a js bundling solution. It's not clear to me if that means I also must then NOT use import maps, or have any of it's benefits?

Can someone help me understand whether these can be used at the same time or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Importmaps* work with `import` statements, *esbuild* will remove all imports. It doesn't really make sense to use *importmaps* on top of *esbuild*. However, you can use them in parallel so to speak. Just create two javascript entry files, one processed by *esbuild* and the other left untouched for use with *importmaps*.

```
<%= javascript_importmap_tags "application_importmap" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "application_esbuild", defer: true %>
```

---

If you have `import` statements in *application.js* and you use *esbuild*, it will smoosh all the imports together into one file, plus transpile, compile, and whatever else you set it up to do. There are no `import` statements left after that and you get the familiar gobbledygook bundle:

```js
// application.js

(() => {
  var __defProp = Object.defineProperty;
  var __getOwnPropNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames;
  var __esm = (fn, res) => function __init() {
    return fn && (res = (0, fn[__getOwnPropNames(fn)[0]])(fn = 0)), res;
  };
...
```

If you use *importmaps*, there is no preprocessing of any kind and all the `import` statements stay untouched. Actual importing is delegated to the browser. This is where *importmaps* do the work, *application.js* and other files are untouched:

```js
// application.js

import "@hotwired/turbo-rails";
```

*Importmaps* tell the browser where to find *@hotwired/turbo-rails*, for example. Because it is not a URL browser can fetch it has to be mapped to a URL. This is why you're making those pins. They take care of making a mapping to a relative or remote URL. Relative URLs are handled by *sprockets* and automatically updated on file changes.

```html
<script type="importmap" data-turbo-track="reload">{
  "imports": {
    "@hotwired/turbo-rails": "/assets/turbo-5605bff731621f9ca32b71f5270be7faa9ccb0c7c810187880b97e74175d85e2.js",
    "application": "/assets/application-0fe7d3d5e7e66b4e14e543d5e9caa2c8eaabde6653ad2d873c4ddc3dea81f0fd.js"
  }
}</script>
```

If your *application.js* is processed by *esbuild* there is nothing left to do for *importmaps*.

Maybe you could just transpile *jsx* and leave *import*s untouched, but that feels like an overkill of a set up.

To keep it simple, pick one or the other: stick to basic javascript and use *importmaps*, otherwise use *esbuild*.

---

*https://github.com/WICG/import-maps*

Comment: I do already understand the basics of importmaps, but there might be a couple things about the setup in rails that I'm still not clear on. It sounds like you're saying that they are not mutually exclusive and can be used together but in different javascript files. This is compelling to me, since I could probably get 90% of my NPM modules this way. But simplicity is also compelling....

Comment: If my understanding is correct, could I ask you to precede your answer with something clear answering the question, then I'll "accept" it as the answer. Something like "Yes they can be used at the same time, but it is not the simplest implementation."

Comment: @pixelearth updated. yes you could use both just not for the same `application.js` file.